# Koalefant doesn't appear when following trail at night

Tags: dont-starve

I tried following the trail at night a few times, but about at the 8th footprint, character doesn't say anything like "animal must be near" and no further traces appear. I suppose it could be a bug, but maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Also, I'm playing with the Reign of Giants DLC content enabled.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, or maybe you're not finding the last footprint. It appears to me ROG fixed a lot of "trail error" bugs on the koalefant, ensuring you more often track a beast after following its trail.